# unable convert &lt;p&gt;&lt; to <, >, etc in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a problem with ckeditor.

I have typed "Hello World" in textarea. But the result was:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;
```

I have changed config.js in /ckeditor/config.js :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
     config.language = 'eng';
};

CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;   
CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek= false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin= false;  
CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
```

It didn't work. Can you help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried on the CKEDITOR forums? http://ckeditor.com/comment/51028#comment-51028

Comment: Nothing happened.. :(

Comment: Umm, do you care to elaborate a little? WHen does the encoded string appear? Does it appear in CKE wysiwyg mode or source mode? Or does it appear after you save the contents to a DB and display it after? Or does it appear in like a preview element? Does it appear immediately when you start typing within the editor area? Do you have a default value for the editor? What version of CKE? http://jsfiddle.net/qdndP/125/ seems to work for me.

Comment: Both of them, in wysiwyg and source mode. For example, i typed "Hello World". in DB: &lt;p&gt;hello world&lt;/p&gt;

When I saw in browser: <p>hello world</p>.

No, i don't have a default value. I set empty for it. I use CKE 4.2.2 version. Oh, I use codeigniter too.

Comment: Still sounds like a standard encoding issue to me, it's already broken in the database (as far as I can see). What code do you use to save it? Have a look at the entire chain from editor to database and see where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Please change config.htmlEncodeOutput = false; to config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;
I did test, it is ok

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue for you, but this solved my issue:

```
CKEDITOR.document.getById('textbox_id').setHtml('your text');
```

Hope this help.